# Create user with install4j for linux installer

Tags: install4j

I have a requirement where I am installing with sudo as I need root access for some actions.
I have to create couple of unix users with install4j and then use these users in systemd file to start a particular service.

I was not able to find any action for creating users. So I have used *Run executable or batch file* action to run a shell script for adding users and giving proper ownership using these users to certain directories.

I have 2 questions here :

1. Is this approach good for creating users ? or any better approach is available
2. If any of the command in shell script fails, installer can fail..but users are not aware of what went wrong.

Please pardon me , I am new to install4j

Answer (score 0):

As of install4j 8, there is no elevation of privileges for Linux/Unix media files.

The recommendation is to run the entire installer with sudo, if elevated privileges are required.

Comment: thanks for the response . Yes I am running the installer with sudo. Is there any recommended way to create users via installer ?

Comment: Also , is there a way I can check , if the user exists on system ?

Comment: No, install4j has no functionality to work with users on Linux/Unix systems.